# Can a creature be True Polymorphed into a corpse and then raised?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, resurrection

*Inspired by [If a corpse is polymorphed into a creature, does it retain personality?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129279/28917)*

[*True Polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) can turn a creature into an object

> **Creature into Object**. If you turn a creature into an object, it transforms along with whatever it is wearing and carrying into that form. The creature's statistics become those of the object, and the creature has no memory of time spent in this form, after the spell ends and it returns to its normal form.

Since [a corpse is an object](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55951/28917), a creature can be *True Polymorphed* into a corpse.

Can it then be raised, by a spell such as *revivify* or *true resurrection*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### No.

Let's check the spell descriptions and find out why not.

[True Resurrection](http://dnd5e.wikia.com/wiki/True_Resurrection):

> **You touch a creature that has been dead for no longer than 200 years** and that died for any reason except old age. If the creature's soul is free and willing, it's restored to life with all its hit points.

Since the polymorphed creature is not dead, it cannot be resurrected using true resurrection.

[Revivify](http://dnd5e.wikia.com/wiki/Revivify):

> **Touch a creature that's died in the last minute.** It returns to life with 1 hit point. This spell can't return life to a creature that died of old age, and it can't restore missing body parts.

Since our polymorphed creature has not died in the last minute, they cannot be revivified.

[Raise Dead](http://dnd5e.wikia.com/wiki/Raise_Dead):

> **Touch a creature dead for no longer than 10 days.** If its soul is both willing and at liberty to rejoin the body, the creature returns to life with 1 hit point. This spell has no effect on undead.

Since the polymorphed creature is not dead, they cannot be brought back using Raise Dead.

Since [spells only do what they say they do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107637/what-is-the-source-of-the-spells-do-only-what-they-say-they-do-rules-interpret), I do not think true polymporph can be combined with any of the above spells.

Comment: Wait, how is a corpse not dead? Could you explain that?

Answer (score 16):

## Nope.

Raise Dead, True Resurrection, and so forth don't target "corpse".  They target "creature that has died".  You might be able to use True Polymorph to create something that is in every way the physical recreation of a dead body, but if it didn't start out as a creature and then die, it's not a valid target for that line of spells.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97762/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-barden-can-a-creature-be-true-polymorphed-into-a-cor).