# How does casting Animate Dead on a True Polymorphed corpse get resolved?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, polymorph, animated-objects

Inspired by some [similar](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129279/28917) [questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/129283/can-a-creature-be-true-polymorphed-into-a-corpse-and-then-raised) and a comment on [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/129286/15689), I'm curious how one might resolve the casting of *animate dead* on a creature who has been *true polymorph*ed into a corpse.

The description of the [*true polymorph*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/true-polymorph) spell states:

> Choose one creature or nonmagical object that you can see within range. You transform the creature into a different creature, **the creature into an object**, or the object into a creature (the object must be neither worn nor carried by another creature).
>
> [...]
>
> ***Creature into Object.*** If you turn a creature into an object, **it transforms along with whatever it is wearing and carrying into that form. The creature’s statistics become those of the object**, and the creature has no memory of time spent in this form, after the spell ends and it returns to its normal form.

If indeed a corpse or pile of bones could be considered an object, and the description of [*animate dead*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/animate-dead) states:

> Choose **a pile of bones or a corpse of a medium or small humanoid.** Your spell raises it as an undead creature. The target becomes a skeleton if you chose bones or a zombie if you chose a corpse.

Hypothetically, could a player use True Polymorph on an enemy, turn them into a corpse, and then use Animate Dead on them to turn them into a zombie?

If so, what would happen once either of the spells wears off (either from the duration expiring or loss of concentration)? How would this be resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**There's nothing stopping you.**

It's pretty straightforward, really.

- You transform the creature into a corpse with *true polymorph*.  Check.  You can do that (as long as it fails or forgoes its save).  It's now a corpse which, upon dispel of the *true polymorph* effect, will revert to being a living creature.
- You cast *animate dead* on the corpse.  Check.  The corpse is now affected by an *animate dead* enchantment, and functions as a mindless undead creature.  It will still revert to being a living creature upon dispel of the *true polymorph* effect (which, among other things, will happen if it is reduced to 0 HP)
- If the resulting undead is destroyed utterly without being reverted to 0 HP, however (via an effect like disintegrate or turn undead) then the physical body is destroyed and does not revert, thus killing the original living creature.  This is a fresh and novel way to kill an enemy, admittedly, but you could also have chosen to *true polymorph* them into an inanimate object, and left them somewhere that they were unlikely to be found.

Comment: Alternatively, if you wanted to turn a creature into a zombie, you could skip the animate dead bit and just True Polymorph them straight into a zombie...

Comment: What is the reason the true polymorph wears off if the zombie is reduced to 0 hp?

Comment: @Erik from the spell's description: "The transformation lasts for the duration, or until the target drops to 0 hit points or dies."

Comment: @IsaacReefman but then they'd have their original personality, rather than having the default mindless obedience of the animated dead.