# Can an unconscious creature hold their breath?

Tags: dnd-5e, conditions, unconscious, breathing

Does an unconscious creature or PC automatically hold their breath as pertaining to suffocation?

As pertaining to this question:
[Is the act of suffocating itself considered to be taking damage?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/148966/51396)

> A creature can hold its breath for a number of minutes equal to 1 + its Constitution modifier (minimum of 30 seconds).
>   When a creature runs out of breath or is choking, it can survive for a number of rounds equal to its Constitution modifier (minimum of 1 round). At the start of its next turn, it drops to 0 Hit Points and is dying, and it can’t regain Hit Points or be stabilized until it can breathe again.

The question revolves around the first part “A creature **can** hold its breath. As opposed to *A creature holds its breath*

Comment: The linked question presents this exact scenario (0 HP is unconscious) - if there is something different, please let us know so we can reopen.

Comment: @NautArch I have edited the question, it may have the same or similar answer but I was not intending to imply the creature was at 0 hit points or drowning.

Comment: My point is that unconscious is the same thing as 0 HP. It's still identical, just a different way of saying it.

Comment: Also, even if you *can* hold your breath, that is a conscious thought to override a semi autonomic muscle. Unconscious loses that ability, and the autonomic system takes over and drives you to breath no matter what the environment/situation is.

Comment: @NautArch unconscious and at 0hp are _not_ equivalent.  Sleeping implies unconsciousness, for one thing.  Alternately, consider the difference between a banshee's Wail, which says that creatures that fail the save "drop to 0 hit points" and would definitely cause death saves, and a chasme's Drone, which says that creatures that fail the save "fall unconscious for 10 minutes," which I would not expect to cause death saves.  Unconscious is a condition like any other, and dropping to 0hp causes unconsciousness, but being unconscious does not imply you're at 0hp.

Comment: @LouisWasserman If you're at 0 HP [you are unconscious](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#FallingUnconscious). THe first question asks about being at 0 HP, which includes being unconscious. This question asks about being unconscious. Same thing.

Comment: THat linked question directly is asking "I'm unconscious and at 0HP, how does suffocating interact with that?". That's what this question is asking, too - except for the 0HP bit. But that's ancillary.