# Does Enlarge/Reduce also reduce a monster’s max hit points?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, creature-size, hit-points

From the **Monster Manual** intro, on p. 7, under ["Hit Points"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/monsters#HitPoints):

> A monster's size determines the die used to calculate its hit points, as shown in the Hit Dice by Size table.

[*Enlarge/Reduce*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/enlarge-reduce) gives an option to reduce the target's creature size by one level.

> **Reduce**. The target's size is halved in all dimensions, and its weight is reduced to one-eighth of normal. This reduction decreases its size by one category - from Medium to Small, for example.

When a creature's Constitution modifier decreases, [its maximum hit points decrease as well](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/46701/what-happens-to-hp-when-constitution-decreases).

Following this logic, **does using Reduce on a monster also reduce its maximum hit points?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## No, it won't reduce its max HP.

This spell details exactly every change effected by the spell. Changing hit points is not listed, so it doesn't happen.

While creature size is used for *initially* calculating the max hit points of a *new custom monster*, no rule states that a creature's hit dice change when a creature changes size during play. The guidelines given in that section have no effect outside of it.